# Android wear notification icon is getting replaced by handheld app launcher icon

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

Just playing a bit with Android Wear stuff, Is there any way of having different notification icon for Android Wear and the handheld app icon? The icon displayed in Watch is the launcher icon of handheld app. Even if I change the launcher icons in Wear module or the small icon property of notification, in Android wear notification its still showing handheld device launcher icons. When I put some icon in .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_wear) it is shown as a small icon there in the notification of handheld device but it is not reflected back to wear notification.

There are some similar questions asked in SO but could not find a appropriate solution. Is there any way to change them?